# How to display a custom FBML tab only after a visitor clicks Like

Tags: facebook

Looking for something similar to answer for *Display content after clicking Facebook Like button* but within FB not on website.

Have 2 custom tabs but would prefer if 1 or both could be hidden to Page visitor until the page has been Liked as an incentive to Like the page.

Access to special or free content would be the incentive to Like. Must be possible but just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, but even better show the tab and for its content use facebook's [visible-to-connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/) to show the content to people who have liked, and then create a fb:else (read the comments) to show the like button to people who haven't already liked it.  It will automatically switch once someone clicks 'Like'

Check out [this link](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-fan-pages-content-for-fans-only-static-fbml/) also for more information